# Conditional Array... elegant way to do that

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have this array where several elements must be added or not depending on certain conditions. Normally I would do something like that:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:@"aaa"];
[myArray addObject:@"bbb"];

if (flag)
  [myArray addObject:@"flag"];

if (box)
  [myArray addObject:@"box"];

[myArray addObject:@"xxx"];

if (x > 5)
  [myArray addObject:@"smaller"];

if ([self isMenuVisible])
  [myArray addObject:@"menu"];

... etc.
```

but this appears confusing and complex.

I can imagine several methods I could create to do that, but this would involve passing a dictionary, an array of objects and conditions, etc., but all appear more lame and more complex than this.

How do you guys would do that in a more elegant way?

Comment: That doesn't look confusing or complex to me.  I would do it that way.

Comment: Side note - remember that the tags you apply to the question should be relevant to the content of the question. This question has nothing to do with iOS, the iPhone, or the iPad. It's an Objective-C question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just leave this alone. It is already very clear and easy to understand.

---

**But** you could define a category method if you really hate seeing the `if`.

```
// Not tested.
@implementation NSMutableArray (ext)
-(void)addObject:(NSObject*)obj when:(BOOL)condition {
    if (condition) {
        [self addObject:obj];
    }
}
@end

....

[myArray addObject:@"aaa"];
[myArray addObject:@"bbb"];
[myArray addObject:@"flag" when:flag];
[myArray addObject:@"box" when:box];
[myArray addObject:@"xxx"];
[myArray addObject:@"smaller" when:(x > 5)];
[myArray addObject:@"menu" when:[self isMenuVisible]];
```

This may be a maintenance burden in the future though.

Comment: a class category is a good idea!!!! Thanks!!! Do you have 179,000 points?!!! WTF, I am sweating blood to have 5K! 

Comment: Nice solution.  However, it only really saves whitespace doesn't it and as you mention, might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @RubberDuck You get a lot more points answering questions than asking them. If you wish to gain more points, you need to spend time helping others. Good luck.

Comment: @trojanfoe - not really, it makes the code compact and easier to the eyes.